# Why output redirection is not working?

Tags: bash, sed, io-redirection

Let's say I have a file named 'newfile' . Now I do some text substitution using sed command

```
sed 's/text1/text2/' newfile > newfile
```

In the above command I am subsituting text1 with text2 and then redirecting the output to the samefile. However after executing this command when I use

```
cat newfile
```

An empty file is showed.

What's the problem here?

Comment: You wan to use `sed -i 's/text1/text2/' newfile` so you don't clobber the file before it is processed.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549